# Paralleize Pandas df.iterrows() by GPU kernel

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I write a python program and in that program I need to check if a given value is in a column of the given dataset. To do so I need to iterate over each row and to check equality for the column in each row. It takes a lot of time therefore I want to run it in GPU. I have experience in CUDA C/C++ but not in PyCuda to parallelize it. Could anyone can help me to solve this problem?

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    s1 = set(df.iloc[index]['prop'])
    if temp in s1:
        df.iat[index, df.columns.get_loc('prop')] = 's'
```

> Note: This is a part of my program. I want to parallelize only this
> part using GPU.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you just use `np.where`?

Comment: Actually I didn't use "np.where" and  I think that it doesn't work in a parallel way, at least not as GPU. For my case I have large dataset.

Comment: The reason why you're looking for a parallel version is because of speed. Iterating through rows via `df.iterrows` is extremely slow. `np.where` leverages C code and is very fast. Try it and see whether it speeds up to your liking.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. There is an issue that when I use `np.where` then I should use `contains()` method to check if corresponding cell contains that  `temp` value (is string) or not. But the column `prop` contains only comma seperated keywords and I want to check that if `temp` is one of the keywords or not.

For example:
A sample row: [abc, def, gjh]
If `temp` is `ab` then it shouldn't work but with `contains()` it will work.

Maybe there are another ways to solve it. If you share you experience I would be glad. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Split it to a sublist. Then either `temp in sublist` or explode and operate on columns (which is faster).

Comment: Should I use `np.where()` in that case, if it is possible could you please share that code?

Comment: Do you really want to set it to `s` if temp is in it?

Comment: yes I want to set `s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The motivation for this approach is a means to get out of the `df.iterrows` paradigm due to its relatively low speed. While it might be possible to split into a `dask` dataframe and execute some kind of parallel `apply` function, I think that a vectorised approach is acceptably quick due to Numpy/Pandas vectorised operation performance advantages (depicted below).

[image]

---

The way I interpret this code is basically "In the `prop` column if the variable `temp` is in a list in that column, set the `prop` column to `'s'`".

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    s1 = set(df.iloc[index]['prop'])
    if temp in s1:
        df.iat[index, df.columns.get_loc('prop')] = 's'
```

I construct a test dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'temp': ['re'] * 7, 
                   'prop': [['re', 'a'], ['ad', 'ed'], ['see', 'contra'], ['loc', 'idx'], 
                            ['reader', 'pandas'], ['alpha', 'omega'], ['a', 'z']]})
```

Then explode to get all the possible combinations of `temp` against `prop` sublist elements. Within each resulting group, I aggregate with `any` and use this as the masking key for replacing the corresponding `prop` index with `'s'`.

```
>>> df['result'] = df['prop'].explode().eq(df['temp']).groupby(level=0).any()
>>> df['prop'] = df['prop'].mask(df['result'], 's')
>>> # df['prop'] = np.where(df['result'], 's', df['prop'])  # identical operation

  temp              prop  result
0   re                 s    True
1   re          [ad, ed]   False
2   re     [see, contra]   False
3   re        [loc, idx]   False
4   re  [reader, pandas]   False
5   re    [alpha, omega]   False
6   re            [a, z]   False
```

This answer is robust to row-by-row changes in the `temp` column as well as a (relatively arbitrary) number of elements in `prop` sublists. That said, if your data is large, you should subset first to minimise memory usage. Select only the applicable columns then execute.

Note also that `df['prop'].explode().eq(df['temp'])` works because the `temp` column is broadcasted on index to the exploded `prop` column.

Comment: That is what I wanted. Thanks a lot:) @ifly6